# Do I need a custom recovery to install CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I want to install CyanogenMod on my Galaxy S4. Do I need to install a custom recovery first in order to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to install a custom recovery in order to install Cyanogenmod.

Answer (score 2):

In order to install most ***any*** ROM, **you need** to install custom recovery first. I assume by asking this question, you may also be wondering **why.** Flashing a new ROM or recovery happens before Android is running. Basically, when you're rooting your device you're getting ***root permission***, which is full access to your Android OS. Truly administrative privilages, and only you can limit/extend your own rules. This is much like Linux, Ubuntu and any other Linux-based operating system, though when we talk about Android it's a different story. [Sort of, but in a similar respect. Android is Linux.]

**Why you need custom recovery:** The main advantage of creating a custom recovery is to provide a way to reset an Android device when it may be impossible to boot into it. In addition, it is an environment separate from Android that allows diagnostic updates, and the ability to perform factory resets.

You can use **[Odin](http://www.mediafire.com/download/m9gt0bgu2d8nwg5/andromint-Odin-v3-09.zip)** to root your device, it's easiest in my opinion.

Comment: Or even easier, if you use windows, you can just use [cyanogenmod's installer](http://beta.download.cyanogenmod.org/install), which does everything for you.

Comment: Good call, Compro01

Comment: Odin worked for me on the second try, total rooting process took about 3 minutes, recovery flashed in about 5 seconds, and first boot of new ROM took about 5 minutes all in all! Definitely recommend it too. I used cyanogenmod's installer and it is very good, I just prefer using the recovery out of habit partially. It's so improtant to BACKUP and then backup again just in case, save backup onto PC, the flash new ROM. It fosters good habits in me anyway!